# how to implement variable initialization when loading dll in net?

Tags: c#, dll

made dynamic loading dll using reflection how to implement variable initialization at boot?

```
 private bool loadPlugins( string path )
        {
            try
            {
                string[] pluginFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");

        plugins = new List<IPlugin>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < pluginFiles.Length; i++ )
        {
            string args = pluginFiles[i].Substring(pluginFiles[ i ].LastIndexOf( "\\" ) + 1, pluginFiles[ i ].IndexOf( ".dll" ) -
                pluginFiles[ i ].LastIndexOf( "\\" ) - 1 );

            Type ObjType = null;
            try
            {
                Assembly ass = null;
                AssemblyName myAssemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(pluginFiles[i].ToString());
                ass = Assembly.Load(myAssemblyName/*args*/);
                var s = ass.FullName;
                if ( ass != null )
                {
                    ObjType = ass.GetType(args + ".PlugIn");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;       //если плагин корявый переходим к следующей итерации;
            }

            try
            {
                if ( ObjType != null )
                {
                    plugins.Add( (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance( ObjType ) );
                    plugins[ plugins.Count - 1 ].Host = this;

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you meant by `variable initialization`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused between instance and `Assembly`. I believe you are trying to set value of a variable in some class in this assembly. Now, variables come into existence only when you create the instance of said class.

If you take a look at `Assembly.CreateInstance` method, it does allow you to set values as well. However, these can only be constructor parameters. If these are variables outside of constructor parameter, you can make use of something like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");
        Type objectType = assembly.GetType("TypeName");

        object dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        objectType.GetField("VariableName").SetValue(dynamicObject, "FieldValue");
```

Comment: sorry I probably incorrectly asked 
I need to implement an analogue standard procedure 

BOOL WINAPI DllMain (
    _In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL, 
    _In_ DWORD fdwReason, 
    _In_ LPVOID lpvReserved 
  );

Comment: Ah! Many consider DllMain to be evil. In C# world, recommendation would be to have a static constructor in the class that is exported and do initialization there.

Comment: May be if you can provide more details of what are trying to do, better help can be provided by someone.

Comment: sorry I probably incorrectly asked 
I need to implement an analogue standard procedure 

BOOL WINAPI DllMain (
    _In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL, 
    _In_ DWORD fdwReason, 
    _In_ LPVOID lpvReserved 
  );

Comment: Thank you. I understand your answer. 
But what if the initialization consumes a lot of resources and would like to do before you start working with the exported functions.